# pandas: include aggregation function "count" in one .apply(lambda x: ... )

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I have the following code, computing a few aggregations after doing groupby of the data frame `df`:

```
df_count = df.groupby(['id','target']).size().reset_index(name='counts')

df_gp = df.groupby(['id','target']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'min_duration': min(x['duration']), \
                                    'max_duration': max(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration':sum(x['duration']), \
                                    'all_status':list(x['status']), \
                                    'last_status':list(x['status'])[-1], \
                                    'all_src':list(x['src'])
                                   })).reset_index()

df_update = pd.merge(df_count, df_gp, on = ['id',  'target'], how = 'left')
```

The code works fine, but I am wondering can I put the `count` function in the `df_gp` directly, rather than creating a separate data frame then merge? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

```
df_gp = df.groupby(['id','target']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'min_duration': min(x['duration']), \
                                    'max_duration': max(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration':sum(x['duration']), \
                                    'all_status':list(x['status']), \
                                    'last_status':list(x['status'])[-1], \
                                    'all_src':list(x['src']),\
                                    'count':len(x['src'])# adding len here
                                   })).reset_index()
```